# Trying to get the text of a Paypal New Subscriber email

Tags: google-apps-script

I hit a wall here with this script. I am trying to get the body of a PayPal email that tells me I have a new subscription. I need the email address of the new subscriber. So...

1. I get the thread
2. I get the body. It's full of CSS and code, I don't see any info on the use. On the web page in the source it's all code it seems.
3. When I output it to a spreadsheet Show modal dialog it's looks perfect. I see the email address I am trying to get.
4. Is there a way to get that text? Then I can get the email address and the rest is EASY for me :-).

I hope I'm explaining things right.
This is far as I get with trying to get the text from this.
Thanks for any help you can spare. Maybe this is way over my head in which case, I'll drop it. But I just need the email address from this!

```
function getEmailFromFolder() {
  // Log the subject lines of the threads labeled with MyLabel
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("NewVWMember");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
  var body = message.getBody();
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(body);
  //var n = body.search("mailTo");
  
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(output, 'I want this!');
}
```

Comment: Since it's part of the body you will have to que off of some unique element in the text or possibly collect all email addresses in the body with regular expressions.  Share with us what the body looks like (be careful not to share private information).

Comment: HI cooper and thank you for your time. I left a comment below with my dilemma. there's no normal text to search. Only html css and other code in the body. I guess it has to be rendered when it's displayed? the modal dialog is where I can see the email as in my gmail folder. but if i open the email in GAS get the body and export to a file to look at it, it's nothing but code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You can use a regular expression to extract all emails out of a string.*

#### Regular Expression:

There are multiple diffent ways of doing this, an example would be the following:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g
```

**Rundown of this regular expression:**

- `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+`: matches the username - any number of characters from `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `.` and `_`
- `@` matches the literal character `@`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+`: matches the domain - again like the username, any number of characters from `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `.` and `_`
- `\.`: macthes the literal character `.`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+`: matches the top-level domain, as beforethis can be any number of characters from `[A-Z]`, `[a-z]`, `[0-9]`, `.` and `_`.
- `g`: returns globally, so will not return after the first email has been found.

You can test out the regular expression on RegEx101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/VgEQ9R/1).

#### Email Extraction:

With the regular expression, you can extract an array of email addresses from the message body with just a few extra lines of code:

```
function getEmailFromFolder() {  
  var regex = /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/g;

  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("NewVWMember");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var body = message.getBody();
  
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(body);  
  var emails = output.getContent().match(regex).toString();    
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(emails);

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModalDialog(html, 'I want this!');
}
```

Here, `output` is a string of all the email addresses in the message. It needs to be converted to string to display in the modal dialog, but you can do with this as you see fit.

#### References:

- [Regular Expression - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)
- [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: thank you! the problem is, when i take the email and get the body and save it to a file, I get nothing but code. I can't see the text of the email that i can see with showmodaldialog. there is no way for me to get the body and search the text, i can only search code, Css and html and whatever else is in there. so somehow i need to render the code and then take it and search that. am i making sense???

Comment: Is it the HTML content of the email message? The regex should extract out the email addresses all the same

Comment: Thanks Rafa! I appreciate your time. The html is not the contents of the email. That’s the problem. Say the email says Tony as the new subscriber. There is NO ‘Tony’ in the body. I guess it has to be rendered. When I send it to showmodaldialog I guess it renders. But when I get them email, get the body, save the body to a file, so I can view it, it’s 16 pages of html, css and other stuff. That’s my problem. I guess I need to get the contents somehow and then search there. I don’t know how. This is so I can send new subscribers a welcome email and tips for navigate the lessons on the site.

Comment: @tonymiceli Can you provide a sanitised copy of the email so I can inset it and take a look?

Comment: @tonymiceli I think I get what you mean, I've done a bit of tweaking of the code in my answer. Can you take a look?

Comment: OMG I'm so happy. you did it! I can not thank you enough for helping me. It pulled out an email address. I'll look this over. You made my day. I really spent a long time on this trying to figure it out. I'm such a newbie at this. Thank you so much!